# Usage of "with" function

Tags: android, animation, kotlin

is there somebody who can explain me what "with" function is used for?

Signature

```
public inline fun <T, R> with(receiver: T, f: T.() -> R): R = receiver.f()
```

Doc

> Calls the specified function f with the given receiver as its receiver and returns its result.

And I found its using on this project [Antonio Leiva](https://github.com/antoniolg/Bandhook-Kotlin). It was using for moving view :

```
fun View.animateTranslationY(translationY: Int, interpolator: Interpolator) {
    with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "translationY", translationY.toFloat())) {
        setDuration(context.resources.getInteger(R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime).toLong())
        setInterpolator(interpolator)
        start()
    }
}
```

I was thinking that I know the meaning to I transfer it to

```
fun View.animateTranslationX(translationX: Int, interpolator: Interpolator) {
    with(ObjectAnimator()) {
        ofFloat(this, "translationX", translationX.toFloat())
        setDuration(context.resources.getInteger(R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime).toLong())
        setInterpolator(interpolator)
        start()
    }
}
```

but it doesn't compile ... But I think that `ObjectAnimaton` is receiver and it get everything what I will call in `{}` bracket. Can anybody explain the real meaning and provide a basic example - at least more basic than this? :D

Comment: `with` is the name of the function (with the type parameters `T` and `R`), not a keyword. A keyword is a word with a specific meaning in the language, not with a specific meaning in an API, even if it is the base API.

Comment: u are right, I edited it

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question, I formatted it a bit more if you don't mind. Note that you don't need to repeat the language/runtime in the title, that's what the tags are for.

Comment: Is this android? I see android got tag. Can you please tell me where we can use it in Android? Thanks

Comment: @user1339255 Yes it is Android, u can check the Antonio Leiva.project (link above or https://github.com/antoniolg/Bandhook-Kotlin). He is master in using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is the same as `with` keyword in Pascal.
Anyway, here are three samples with **identical** semantic:

```scala
with(x) {
   bar()
   foo()
}
```

```scala
with(x) {
   this.bar()
   this.foo()
}
```

```scala
x.bar()
x.foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that I understood what "with" do. Look at code:

```
class Dummy {
    var TAG = "Dummy"

    fun someFunciton(value: Int): Unit {
        Log.d(TAG, "someFunciton" + value)
        }
    }

    fun callingWith(): Unit {
    var dummy = Dummy()
    with(dummy, { 
        someFunciton(20) 
    })

    with(dummy) {
        someFunciton(30)
    }

}
```

If I run this code I get one calling of someFunciton with 20 and then with 30 param.

So the code above can be tranfer to this :

```
fun View.animateTranslationX(translationX: Int, interpolator: Interpolator) {
    var obj = ObjectAnimator()
    with(obj) {
        ofFloat(this, "translationX", translationX.toFloat())
        setDuration(context.resources.getInteger(R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime).toLong())
        setInterpolator(interpolator)
        start()
    }
}
```

and I should work - so we have to have var.